# Text wrapping at hyphen in IE7 and below

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am using this bit of jQuery:

```
 $('.myClass').html().replace("-", "&#x2011;");
```

to replace hyphens with non-breaking hyphens to prevent wrapping on text containing....you guessed it: hyphens

This works fine in IE8 and upwards but we have to support IE6 and 7, in which this approach does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because IE 6-7 see a hyphen as a "word break".

The only way I can think to fix it is to wrap the phrase in `<nobr></nobr>` tags.

Eg. `<nobr>word-break</nobr>` which should prevent your issue.

Though without seeing some context it's hard to say how you would do this.

**EDIT**

This info may be helpful: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html

Comment: A simple approach would be to replace x-y (where x and y are any characters) by `<nobr>x-y</nobr>`. Clumsy, and not by any HTML standard, but works on every browser.

Comment: That's exactly what I said :)

Comment: my point was that you could just take two characters on each side of the hyphen, instead of trying to recognize words. E.g., instead of `<nobr>word-break</nobr>` you could more easily generate `wor<nobr>d-b</nobr>reak`.

Comment: @3rror404: Worked great thanks, would vote up but I don't have enough reputation yet!